# Another picture problem

Tags: cipher, visual

Another picture puzzle. Replace the question mark. Once again, the information needed is there. So, try replace it!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are

> exactly 26 vertical bands in the "question" image. If we map these to letters of the alphabet in the obvious way and guess that subdivision means multiple copies of a letter, we get AEEEHIIMNNSSTTTTW, an anagram of WHAT IS TEN TIMES TEN.

The answer to this is

> 100

which clearly corresponds to

> the second of the "answer" images on offer.

Comment: Well done, 100(option 2 is correct) :)

Comment: I am unsure as to why 100 corresponds to that option.

Comment: @Voldemort's Wrath, there are 10 bars in total. The 1st bar represent 0, the 2nd represent 1, and so on til the last one which represent 9. So we have two of 0 and one of 1. Together they can form the number 100.